# How to use multiple barcode scanners each in a column in excel?

Tags: excel, barcode, barcode-scanner

we are using ADVISION AD-2200-W scanners and i want to split the input into columns -one column for each scanner- and i don't know how.

i tried searching for activex barcode control to try and bind each scanner to a column but they removed it then I tried creating a python script but I couldn't identify the scanners. I've tried other things but none worked I've been googling this for 2 days

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.